# how can I merge two tree views?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have two tree views, how can I merge it in one but still have the same number of lines because my problem is that I wanna separate a line into two as i didn't find a solution I created the two tree views, so if there is another way to separate the line without creating the two views is better.

```html
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="medical_lab_cash_tree_id">
    <field name="name">cash</field>
    <field name="model">medical.lab.patient</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
            <field name="patient_id"/>
            <field name="Amount_in_date"/>
            <field name="Amount_In"/>
            <field name="type_In"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
    
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="medical_lab_cash_tree_id2">
    <field name="name">cash2</field>
    <field name="model">medical.lab.patient</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>    
            <field name="patient_id"/>
            <field name="Amount_in_date1"/>
            <field name="Amount_In1"/>
            <field name="type_In1"/>  
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can inherit original view and add as needed fields in tree view.

For example:

```
<record id="medical_lab_cash_tree_id_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">medical.lab.cash.tree</field>
    <field name="model">medical.lab.patient</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="module_name.medical_lab_cash_tree_id"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <field name="type_In" position="after">
            <field name="Amount_in_date1"/>
            <field name="Amount_In1"/>
            <field name="type_In1"/> 
         </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

**EDIT:** You can replace your whole tree with following style.

```
<record id="medical_lab_cash_tree_id_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">medical.lab.cash.tree</field>
    <field name="model">medical.lab.patient</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="module_name.medical_lab_cash_tree_id"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="/tree" position="replace">
            <tree>
                <!-- Place your new field list -->
            </tree>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: here I will have `Amount_in_date1` , `Amount_In1` , `type_In1` and `Amount_in_date` , `Amount_In` , `type_In` in the same line  thing that I'm trying to avoid

Comment: I need that the fields of first tree be in a line, the fields of the second tree in another line

Comment: thanks for ur answer ... but now with the new changes u made fields `Amount_in_date`,`Amount_In`,`type_In` of `medical_lab_cash_tree_id` are empty